# How to backfeed the first printable label before printing next job with help of ZPL in zebra bluetooth printer

Tags: bluetooth, zebra-printers, zpl

[image: print label illustration]

After printing the first label second print onwards gap is coming more gap is coming on label like below format.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the Printer through the web interface if that is available.